# How to set breakpoints using firebug

Tags: firebug, firefox3.6, breakpoints

I'm using Firebug (for the first time) on Firefox 3.6.8 on MacOS X 10.6.7.  The Firebug documentation says that you can set a breakpoint just by clicking on the source line.   That's not happening for me -- it's like the source window doesn't have focus or something.

Here's the browser screen duump (below).  What do I need to do to set breakpoints and debug a simple local script?  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `Script` tag on top, then click a line number there.